# MSB3021 Unable to copy file could not find part of path error when running Service Fabric app in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have a Service Fabric solution that contains multiple projects. I can run all but one of them on my local cluster without issue, but one particular project will not deploy due to the following issue:

> MSB3021   Unable to copy file
>   "C:\Path\To\Repo\src\MyProject\MyService\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\win7-x64\PubTmp\Out\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions.dll"
>   to
>   "C:\Path\To\Repo\src\MyProject\MyService\pkg\Debug\MyServicePkg\Code\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions.dll".
>   Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Path\To\Repo\src\MyProject\MyService\pkg\Debug\MyServicePkg\Code\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions.dll'.

There are two other errors reporting the same issue for `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll` and `runtimeconfig.json` and 30 warnings stating the same issue for random dlls.

I have done all the usual several times:

1. Deleted all `bin`, `obj` and `pkg` directories
2. Stopped local cluster
3. Restarted Visual Studio
4. Restarted machine
5. Checked out repo in a separate directory

The error states that it cannot find part of the path to the `Code` dir in `pkg`, but I have verified that it does exist.

It is strange that this only affects 1 out of several projects. Am I missing anything obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get to the bottom of this issue, I had already deleted the solution directory and re-cloned from the repo and it had not fixed it, albeit in the same parent directory.

In a last ditch attempt I re-cloned the repo in the root of my user directory and it worked fine from then on.

I have no idea what the issue was and why that fixed it.

Comment: PATH TOO LONG.

It is almost surely that those paths that are failing are suddenly TOO LONG.
That is why moving the repo to the root of your user directory did the trick.

Comment: Imagine every piece of software requiring tricks like this?

Comment: I think the accepted answer check-mark is on the wrong answer.

Answer (score 10):

**PATH TOO LONG.**

It is almost surely that those paths that are failing are suddenly TOO LONG.
That is why moving the repo to the root of your user directory did the trick.
It also explains the seeming random nature of the failures and the phenomenon of some projects working and others not; Some have paths that are to long while others don't.

If you copy the failing paths from your output window and paste them in to File Exploder they work fine.

But if you experiment with them from the command line or in a batch file they'll fail.
I'd put money on that being the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I just had a similar issue and it was that the path was too long on a couple of image files in a website project. Shortening the file names allowed the project to be published.

Comment: Must login to upvote you. It saves my life!

Answer (score 2):

I agree to the statement provided by Bart, PATH TOO LONG.

*For anyone facing this issue*, try to clone your codebase/repo to a folder **closer to the root and you can see it working like a magic**.

Of course the error is not intuitive, but the issue is with the length limitation.

Comment: A life-saving solution !!

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to chime in, I was getting the same error and based on the previous answers, I deleted the repo from the Visual Studio suggested location of C:\Users\myusername\Source\Repos and re-cloned it to c:\tfs.  The solution built on the first try after that.

This is on Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.6.5.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

1. Delete reference the other proyect
2. Delete Bin folder with the ddl of the proyect of point 1

Reassign the project reference, compile and publish

Answer (score 0):

This is the perennial issue, the paths are too long
Ensure to check the path and if it is too long, try to keep the folders on root directory. This will resolve the issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My fix was a little different so I'll start with the full error:

```
MSB3021 Unable to copy file "C:\Users\fissh\.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.core\8.10.0.3\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.Core.resources\FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework\Headers\FirebaseCoreDiagnostics-umbrella.h" to "C:\Users\fissh\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\HotRestart\Signing\Sharkbytes.app\out\Sharkbytes.content\Firebase.Core.resources\FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework\Headers\FirebaseCoreDiagnostics-umbrella.h". Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\fissh\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\HotRestart\Signing\Sharkbytes.app\out\Sharkbytes.content\Firebase.Core.resources\FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework\Headers\FirebaseCoreDiagnostics-umbrella.h'. Sharkbytes  C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk\16.4.7090\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets
```

None of the fixes above resolved my issue but they gave me the idea. So to fix my issue I opened

```
C:\Users\fissh\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin
```

and deleted all subfolders. Then I cleaned and rebuilt my project and it worked. I agree with others in this thread that this was a path to long issue.